# numbers of font are larger than letters

Tags: html, css, fonts

im working on a license plate previewing script

everything is going great, except for the fact that in this custom font, numbers are larger than letters despite them having the same `font-size` declared.

here is a screenshot:

[image]

the font is: http://www.dafont.com/mandatory.font

i used the font squirrel generator to get the files and css for it.

heres the css:

```
body {
    margin: 0px 0px;
    background: #3AB54B;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'mandatoryregular';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'mandatoryregular';
    src: url('fonts/mandator-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/mandator-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/mandator-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/mandator-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/mandator-webfont.svg#mandatoryregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

my question is, how can i fix this? im also using php. the only way ive thought of so far is to use php to go through each character and if it is numeric, have it add a `span` around the character then declare a different font size in the css.

but is there a better/easier way?

Comment: The font uses small caps.  It looks like if you did everything in capital letters, the heights should match.

Comment: Numbers has equal height for the CAPS ...

Comment: thank you noah! just used `text-transform: uppercase` and it fixed the issue!

Comment: You should simply use capital letters, instead of using lowercase and then using CSS to fix that.